# change size of imagebutton when clicked

Tags: c#, android, dot42

I have an imagebutton which size I would like change when I click it.
I'm working with dot42 where you can develop android apps in C#

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
button1.Click += delegate { button1.Height = 25; };
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need register event like this:

```
    button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
```

or

```
    button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

and than into your function button1_click write whatever u want to do so for changing size 'd be like :

```
    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Height = 45;
    }
```